# Faster code to find the colored cells (Interior) ,OR speed up `For each` Loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, optimization

I am using below code to select the **colored cells** (interior) on UsedRange exclude First Row.
It works ,but it is slow with huge ranges e.g 20k. 
Is there a faster method or speed up `For each` Loop. 
In advance, grateful for all your help.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
 
  Dim crg As Range      'UsedRange exclude First Row
  Set crg = ws.UsedRange
  Set crg = crg.Offset(1, 0).Resize(crg.Rows.Count - 1, crg.Columns.Count)
 
  Dim mystr, cel As Range, FinalRange As Range
   mystr = ""
     For Each cel In crg
         If cel.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
            mystr = mystr & cel.Address & ","
         End If
      Next
    If mystr = "" Then
        MsgBox "No colored cell found"
     Else
        Set FinalRange = ws.Range(Left(mystr, Len(mystr) - Len(",")))
    End If
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: This question may be better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you're *only* going for highlighted cells, what you have is probably the fastest.  If there is a rule that determines what's highlighted, or if they're all highlighted the same color, might be able to go about this a different way to speed it up.

Comment: FYI it's not safe to build up a range by concatenating cell addresses like that.  If  `mystr` gets too long then when you run `Range(mystr)` you risk "losing" some of your cells.  Use `Application.Union` to build up the range instead.

Comment: @tigeravatar ,yes you can consider the colored cell have only one color `yellow`

Comment: @Leedo Are the cells highlighted via conditional formatting?

Comment: @tigeravatar ,no , the cells are highlighted manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes you can consider the colored cell have only one color yellow

Maybe this kind of code is faster ?

```
Sub test()  
Set crg = ws.UsedRange
Set crg = crg.Offset(1, 0).Resize(crg.Rows.Count - 1, crg.Columns.Count)

  With Application.FindFormat
  .Clear
  .Interior.Color = vbYellow
  .Locked = True
  End With

Dim rg As Range
Set c = crg.Find(What:=vbNullString, SearchFormat:=True)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                If rg Is Nothing Then Set rg = c Else Set rg = Union(rg, c)
                Set c = crg.Find(What:=vbNullString, after:=c, SearchFormat:=True)
            Loop While c.Address <> FirstAddress
        rg.Select
    Else
        MsgBox "no cell with yellow color found"
    End If

End Sub
```

The final result will select all the cells with yellow color or show a message box
So, it doesn't loop to each cell in crg and check if the looped cell color is yellow, but directly find within crg which cell with the yellow color, then get the c as rg variable, find the next cell with yellow color, then union the rg with c.

Comment: Yes, your code is more faster than mine with 10 times.
please, what `.Clear` and `.Locked = True` of FindFormat means ?

Comment: `clear` is to clear whatever current existing format. `locked`, if the range to find is locked and protected ---> true will still find the c, false will not find the c. To better understanding, try to lock and protect your crg range variable, have the `.locked = false`, then step run the sub. It will get that c is nothing and give you the msgbox. Then to check the .clear syntax, after the format is vbyellow, check the Find window by ctrl+f in Excel app, you will see the format color is yellow. Step run the sub passing the .clear syntax - the Find window will give you "No Format Set".